# Disable cut and round

Tags: r

While reading an alphanumeric data file as input file, R automatically performs a cut of the number of decimals of the numbers.

Is there a way to set neither to trim nor to round numbers but read as they are?

Comment: How many digits do you have? Maybe look at `options(digits = ...)`

Comment: I'm using read.delim()

Comment: read.delim and read.csv are simplified version of read.table. See linked post it is not about how you read, it is about how it is printed.